# How to capture every change in the Entry field?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onchange, textchanged

I have this entry field which the user will input the data and then I could like to capture every time the text change and then will query the database if there's a match of data from what the user inputted and then display the results.

```
             <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="16,13,16,9">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
                  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapVINRecognizer"/>
                  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                  <local:CustomLabel x:Name="VINLabel" Text="VIN" TextColor="#3680a4" Style="{StaticResource AccordTitleStyle}"/>
                  <Image x:Name="VINImage" Source="arrow_down.png"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="VINAccordion" IsVisible="True" Padding="0,5,0,16" Spacing="10">
                  <StackLayout Spacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <local:CustomEntry x:Name="VINText" Placeholder="17 CHARACTERS" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                  <local:CustomLabel Style="{StaticResource AccordLabelStyle}">
                    <local:CustomLabel.Text>
                      If the motor has a VIN, enter the VIN. A VIN is the 17 character identifier recorded on most vehicles built after 1998
                    </local:CustomLabel.Text>
                  </local:CustomLabel>
                  <local:CustomButton Clicked="OnClickSearchBtn" ClassId="vin"/>
                </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
```

This lines the user input the text:

```
  <StackLayout Spacing="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <local:CustomEntry x:Name="VINText" Placeholder="17 CHARACTERS" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

How will I capture the text every time it changes? How will I display if there's a result afterwards? U have ready the TextChanged Event but I'm not sure how to use it. Is it applicable to this scenario? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you please remove the XAML that is not relevant to the question, so that it helps people who are trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MVVM approach, use a binding for the entry text property, then you rule!

Answer (score 1):

You can Bind to the [Text property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Text/) of [Entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Entry/) if you are Binding (using a VM) or else you can use the [TextChanged Event](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.TextChanged/).

Since you said you need to query the database on every text change make sure you run it as an [Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) method to ensure that your main thread (UI Thread) is not blocked. Once you fetch the results you can update your UI by making the required changes from the UI thread by using [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/) method.

Eg :

```
VINText.TextChanged += async (s,e) => 
{
    //Long running task - query the db
    await FetchResultFromDatabase();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {            
        // update UI
        label.Text = "Async operation completed";
    });
}
```